# Random Image Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Su ayuda por favor estoy intentando hacer un carousel de imágenes que funcionen cada cierto tiempo. Encontré un código por Internet pero no me funciona. Creo que debe ser por la ruta que tengo en el IMGURL.

Detallo codigos:

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                            <asp:Image ID="img_anden" Style="border: 2px solid black;" alt="First slide" runat="server"></asp:Image>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

```
 Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            img_anden.ImageUrl = "http://localhost:49230/images/gallery/Img1.jpg" + rand.Next(1, 100).ToString() + ".jpg";
```

Comment: En el HTML generado, click derecho, inspeccionar elemento y mira lo que hay :D

Answer (score 0):

La ruta, claramente es incorrecta. 
Es mejor trabajar con rutas relativas como la siguiente.

```
img_anden.ImageUrl = "~/images/gallery/Img" + rand.Next(1, 100).ToString() + ".jpg";
```

Entendiendo que tus imágenes tienen el siguiente patrón:

- El nombre empieza por "Img"
- Detrás de "Img" tienes un número entre el 1 y el 100.
- Tienen la extensión (son del tipo) ".jpg"
- Debes tener 100 imágenes del tipo Img1.jpg, Img2.jpg, ..., Img100.jpg
- Las imágenes deben estar guardadas en la carpeta "images/gallery" del directorio raíz de la aplicación.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! estabas en lo correcto. Era un error de la ruta y justamente tenia todo tal cual pero al cambiar a una ruta relativa funciono!

Answer (score 0):

**La ruta es incorrecta.** 
Como dice Roger es mejor trabajar con las [rutas relativas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). 
Yo recomendaría obtener las imágenes que contenga el folder y luego iterar entre ellas de manera aleatoria eligiendo solo de las opciones disponibles. 
Estoy usando **[LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/working-with-linq)** para obtener un archivo aleatoriamente [`OrderBy(x=>Guid.NewGuid())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449452/linq-order-by-random)

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/gallery"));
var file = files.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
img_anden.ImageUrl = file;
```

Esto suponiendo que todas las imagenes estan en la ruta `/images/gallery` en la raíz de la carpeta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!